# Unable to get access to private variable inside class function

Tags: angular

I am working in an angular project and designing d3 pie charts. Everything works fine. But my problem is that I am not able to access class private 
variable inside a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope issue. Change

```
.attr('y', function (d, i) { return (this.legendHeight * (i + 1))})
```

To

```
.attr('y', (d, i) => { return (this.legendHeight * (i + 1))})
```

[One of many docs](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing can be explaned:
within your `function (d, i) { return (this.legendHeight * (i + 1))}` it so happens to be that `this` referes to another context than you might expect.
try changing it to an Arrow notation, like `(d,i) => this.legendHeight * (i + 1)` to solve your issue.

If you cannot use this notation you will need to make a local reference to your value of legendHeight